# What to key in for if time = 1, if na =0?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula

I'm new in this world. As you can see in the picture, I key in function at B1 and I want B1 to return `1` if A1 data is **time**. But it kept of giving me `0`. At the same time, I want if there are no value or N/A, it must return `0`. What should I key in? I do understand that if using `=ifna("A","1","0")`, but that still does not return me anything for if there are any data.

[image]

Comment: What program is that?

Comment: Is that Excel? Open Office? Google docs? Something else? Please add the respective tag to your question?

Comment: Are you saying you want B1 to be 1 if A1 is formatted as a time value?  You can't ask "is this a time", because Excel stores times as integers.  They look like any other integer.  You only see a time because of the cell formatting.

Comment: This is google sheet. Sorry forgot to tell.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I want B1 to be 1 if the format is time value. And 0 if there is no time value.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a way to do that, but why would you?  If you're writing the formulas, how could you NOT know what's in that cell?

Answer (score 0):

1. Format your column A to "Time"
2. Paste formula to B2: `=IF(ISDATE(A1);1;0)`

**Note**: I'm using Norwegian formatting/settings. For english formatting/settings, change "**;**" with "**,**" in formula.

[image: Example:]

Why your formula won't work:

1. Since you use "" with your hh:mm:ss like this: "hh:mm:ss" - you're asking your formula to look for exactly that. Your formula will only return TRUE if **A1 = hh:mm:ss** (in text)
2. In IF-statements, do not use "" for returning numbers og TRUE/FALSE.

- Your formula: `if(A1="hh:mm:ss","1","0)`
- What needs to be changed in TRUE/FALSE part: `if(A1="hh:mm:ss",1,0)`
  -- Tho, you need to ask if A1 is a date: `=IF(ISDATE(A1),1,0)`

To count for **N/A** - put IFERROR in formula: `=IFERROR(IF(ISDATE(A1),1,0)0)`

Comment: To count for N/A - put **IFERROR** in formula: =IFERROR(IF(ISDATE(A1),1,0)0)